# DocuSignAPI.EnvelopePDF pdf = client.RequestPDF(id)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have downloaded DocuSign-eSignature MS.Net sample from https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

The code runs correctly and gets the documents signed from the recipients.However when we try to download the signed document by clicking Download button available under GetStatusAndDocs section then code mentioned below throws error,

```
This demo has encountered an error: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
Please correct the issue and try again.

 DocuSignAPI.EnvelopePDF pdf = client.RequestPDF(id)
```

This error is encountered only when the document is a pdf file.Works fine in case of text files.

Comment: what's the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change any of the code or are you running the exact .NET version out of the box?  I'm guessing you've changed at least some of the code because you say it works for other file types but does not work for PDFs.  The reason I think that is because if you look in the `DownloadItem()` function at **line 122** in `GetStatusAndDocs.aspx.cs` you'll see:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
```

By default the SDK sets the document content type to PDF so if you haven't changed any code then I'm not sure how it's working for .txt and other file types?